# Check if an Object Key has a property if so, check .length on values

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

How do I check if an Object has a certain key and then count the amount of "values" that key has?

[image]

(Image displays: `numberOfComments` object)

I want to check against `post.id` so something like.

```
if (post.id === Object.keys(numberOfComments) {
   const numOfComment = (numberOfComments Value).length

   return numOfComment

} else if (post.id !== Object.keys(numberOfComments) { 
   const numOfComment = 0
   return numOfComment
}
```

Should return 2 for this case. 
One important feature, of course, is that it needs to be dynamic. The post.id is not always the same.

The meaning of this is to return an object from Redux store check if a post has any comments and if so display the number of comments.

Thank you!

Comment: `(numberOfComments Value)` ???

Comment: So loop over the array with `some()` and see it has an id?

Comment: Well, was more an "I don't know what to write here" I want to grab the values from the key that paste the validation and then check the length (how many items is stored under that key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if an object has a property, you can just use `if( obj[property])`. In your case, you could easily condense your code above in to one line.

`return (numberOfComments[post.id] ? numberOfComments[post.id].length : 0);`

Comment: Interesting is being called at so have to run. Will check this when I get back but it seems like what I'm trying to archive

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

First you check if your object contains the value of post.id in its keys, then if that's true you get the value from numberOfComments[post.id] and return its length, otherwise the post.id was not found and you return 0.

```
if(Object.keys(numberOfComments).indexOf(post.id)) {
  return numberOfComments[post.id].length;
} else {
 return 0;
}
```

cheers